# How to send ERC20 & ERC721 tokens using Safe Core SDK?

Tags: gnosis-safe, gnosis, safe-core-sdk

I am using [Safe Core SDK](https://docs.gnosis-safe.io/build/sdks/core-sdk) in my web app(Next.js) project to generate and deploy Safes on Polygon Testnet(Mumbai) by the users. I can see the functions provided by SDK to [create](https://docs.gnosis-safe.io/build/sdks/core-sdk#3.-create-a-safe-transaction), [sign](https://docs.gnosis-safe.io/build/sdks/core-sdk#3.a.-off-chain-signatures) and [execute](https://docs.gnosis-safe.io/build/sdks/core-sdk#4.-transaction-execution) transactions for Ether/Matic transfer but am not able to understand how to send ERC20 and ERC721 tokens. Can someone please guide how to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To create a token transfer you need to execute the following code:

```
import { SafeTransactionDataPartial } from '@gnosis.pm/safe-core-sdk-types'

const transaction: SafeTransactionDataPartial = {
  to: '<TOKEN_CONTRACT_ADDRESS>',
  value: '0',
  data: '<DATA>'
}
const safeTransaction = await safeSdk.createTransaction(transaction)
```

where `TOKEN_CONTRACT_ADDRESS` is the address of the token contract and `DATA` is the encoding of the call to the transfer method: `contractInstance.methods.transfer(toAddress, amount).encodeABI()`

Comment: Thanks [German](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/89118/germ%c3%a1n).